# Reflections from a EmissiveTexture and ReceivingShadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

Ok. I have a setup where a plane has a texture that is set to emission to have a good reflection on a glassurface on the opposite side. But now the Surface did not receive shadows anymore.

so I tried shadow rays, glossy rays etc feed into a mixshader to darken the shadow area, but nothing works.

So how do I get the plane to reflect properly and the shadows on the glassdoor  too ?

here is a Picture of the setting and as you can see, there is no shadow on the glasssurface:

[image]

This is what i think the Image should look like

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to have some reflection type to windows glass?

Comment: I tried adding the Image as fake reflection in the shader settings but it does not give accurate results and the texture was distorted - is that what you are asking for ?

Comment: No, I am asking where you want the reflections to be shown, on Windows?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, it is actually showing where it should be - but the shadow from the roof is not darken the Windows and not darken the reflection

Comment: okay hang on, I am  giving you a node setup, try applying it on your windows glass shader.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. I am here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this node setup:
[image]

Try applying this to your Windows.
Hope this may be helpful.

Comment: ok, I tried that, but sorry, that does not solve the problem... With your Setup i now have crystal clear reflections of the objects in front of the window but no background. or - when i inverse the Inputs a fully transparent Window.

Maybe ist a missunderstanding - what I need to have is the reflection of the background in the windows and where the shadow hits the window - there should be shadow on the window - but there isn't ! 
So why and how do I get that shadow darken the reflection.

look closely on the Image - you see the shadow border on the wall - and there is non on the windows

Comment: Do you have a reference image?

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Nyb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Nyb.png) so. this is what i think the Image should look like